# Dynamic button and eventhandler with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new at ASP.NET C# and I have to do something to school.
I have to do e-shop. Just easy thing, but I've do it with table. I'm generating table, but last cell depend on user login. If you are not logged in, there is just text.  When you are, in last cell there is textbox named "index" and button named "koupit". When I click on button, it will direct me to page, where is SQL code. That code means, that I can buy my selected item. Everything is almost okay.  I have problem only with the Event handler. It wants some return, but I don't know what it wants.

There is my code:

```
namespace e_shop
{
    public partial class index1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eshop"].ToString();

         string id_item;

      // label, where I will write, that there is some problem            
            private string error = "";
        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                //connect to DB
                //connection string

                //sql connect
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                //buttons
                if (Request.Form["puj_prihl"] != null)
                {
                    //someone click on log in
                    string login = Request.Form["puj_login"];
                    string password = Request.Form["puj_password"];
                    //delete white-spaces
                    login = login.Trim();
                    password = password.Trim();
                    //controll on null
                    if (login.Equals("") || password.Equals(""))
                    {
                        error = "You have to write something";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //try to log in
                        if (Function.userLogin(login, password, sqlConnection))
                        {
                            //you are logged in
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //something is bad
                            error = "Something is bad";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Request.Form["puj_odhl"] != null)
                {
                    //someone click on logout button
                    if (!Function.userLogout())
                    {
                        error = "Something is bad";
                    }
                }
                //div-body
                //get everything about items
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [items]", sqlConnection);
                //Open connection
                sqlConnection.Open();
                //read everything
                SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                //read rows
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    //new row
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    //I need id id
                     id_item = dataReader["ID_item"].ToString();
                    //next cells
                    TableCell tc_name = new TableCell();
                    tc_name.Text = dataReader["name_item"].ToString();
                    TableCell tc_popis = new TableCell();
                    tc_popis.Text = dataReader["popis_item"].ToString();
                    TableCell tc_category = new TableCell();
                    tc_category.Text = dataReader["category_item"].ToString();
                    TableCell tc_price = new TableCell();
                    tc_price.Text = dataReader["price_item"].ToString();
                    //cell for click
                    TableCell tc_click = new TableCell();
                    if (!Funkce.isLoggedIn())
                    {
                        //user isnt logged
                        tc_click.Text = "You have to log in";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Button buy = new Button();
                        buy.Text = "Buy";

                       TextBox index = new TextBox();

                        tc_click.Controls.Add(buy);
                        tc_click.Controls.Add(index);
                        buy.Click+= buy_Click(index, id_item);

                        }



                    //cells to row
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc_name);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc_popis);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc_category);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc_price);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc_click);

                    //row to table
                    table_eshop.Rows.Add(tr);
                }
                //close reader
                dataReader.Close();
                //close connection
                sqlConnection.Close();
                //div-login
                literal_login.Text = "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">\n";
                if (Funkce.isLoggedIn())
                {

                    //if we are logged in we need logout form
                    literal_login.Text += "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"puj_odhl\" value=\"Logout\" />\n";
                    label_who.Text = "<p>Logged user: " + Function.getUserLogin(Session[Session.SessionID].ToString(), sqlConnection) + " </p>\n";
                    my_cart.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //else we need to logg in
                    literal_login.Text += "Login: <input type=\"text\" name=\"puj_login\" /><br />\n";
                    literal_login.Text += "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"puj_password\" /><br />\n";
                    literal_login.Text += "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"puj_prihl\" value=\"Logged in\" />\n";

                }
                literal_login.Text += "</form>\n";
                if (!chyba.Equals(""))
                {
                    label_error.Text = "<p class=\"error\"> " + error + " </p>";
                }

                  }
        }
                //here is problem
                   private EventHandler buy_Click(TextBox index, string id_item)
        {

            string quantity = index.Text;
       Response.Redirect("buy_it.aspx?id=" + id_item + "&quantity=" + quantity);

        }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to edit the comments and translate them to English for a better understanding

Comment: It's not clear at all if there is an error, what the error is, and where the error occurs.  Please specify.

Comment: I hope now its better, everything is english and commented

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Web Form, button control won't be able to trigger server-side click event if you rend as html string.

```
//else we need to logg in
literal_login.Text += "Login: <input type=\"text\" name=\"puj_login\" /><br />\n";
literal_login.Text += "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"puj_password\" /><br />\n";
literal_login.Text += "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"puj_prihl\" value=\"Logged in\" />\n";
```

You need to use Server Controls, and trigger server-side click event like this -

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UsernameTextBox" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordTextBox" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit"
   OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />

// Code Behind
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = UsernameTextBox.Text,
        password = PasswordTextBox.Text;
    bool rememberMe = RememberMeCheckBox.Checked;

    // Retrieve username and hashed password from database, and validate them
    if (username.Equals("johndoe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
        password.Equals("123456", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, rememberMe);
    }
    MessageLabel.Text = "Invalid username or password";
}
```

*I have [a very simple  ASP.NET Web Form Web Application at GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/FormAuthenticationExample) which uses FormAuthentication. Please feel free to clone and test it.*

Comment: Thank you, but this is ok. This is from teacher and I must use it like this. My real problem is with Eventhadler.